# Eclipse RCP: Conditionally enabling/disabling perspective in Perspectie Switcher

Tags: eclipse-rcp

The Open Perspective View shows a list of perspectives to which a user can switch. My custom perspective is there, too. Can I have it not listed or greyed out, if a certain condition `b`is not met?

The second best alternative that comes to my mind is to have it listed, but the actual switch is not carried out, if `b == false`.

Comment: The view is filtered by enabled activities - see the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point.

Comment: I don't understand how to use it

Comment: There is plenty of help available on activties - start in the Eclipse help [here](https://help.eclipse.org/2022-09/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_advext_activities.htm&resultof%3D%2522%256f%2572%2567%252e%2565%2563%256c%2569%2570%2573%2565%252e%2575%2569%252e%2561%2563%2574%2569%2576%2569%2574%2569%2565%2573%2522%2520)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way for me was to use the extension point `org.eclipse.ui.activities`, as greg-449 suggested, and add a propertyTester. In order to hide perspective related UI elements and not every UI element from the same plugin, one can use `isEqualityPattern="true"`.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
<activity
        description="Remove some UI Elements"
        id="com.my.plugin.ui.hideUI"
        name="HideUI">
<enabledWhen>
   <test
         forcePluginActivation="false"
         property="com.my.plugin.ui.PlanningPropertyTester">
   </test>
</enabledWhen>
</activity>

<activityPatternBinding
   activityId="com.btc.edm.hidePlanning"
   isEqualityPattern="true"
   pattern="com.my.plugin.ui/id.of.the.perspective.to.hide">
</activityPatternBinding>
</extension>

<extension
  point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">
<propertyTester
     class="com.my.plugin.ui.MyPropertyTester"
     id="com.my.plugin.ui.propertyTester"
     namespace="com.my.plugin.ui"
     properties="MyPropertyTester"
     type="java.lang.Object">
</propertyTester>
</extension>
```

It is important to have a fully qualified name for type.

The MyPropertyTester class extends `org.eclipse.core.expressions.PropertyTester` and overrides the `test` method.

```
public class MyPropertyTester extends PropertyTester {

    @Override
    public boolean test(Object receiver, String property, Object[] args, Object expectedValue) {
        if (goodWeather()) {
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```